# AWS GLACIER CLI - Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to connect to AWS Glacier through AWS CLI, but when i run it:

```
aws glacier list-vaults --account-id -
```

I got this error:

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://glacier.us-east1.amazonaws.com/-/vaults"
```

I already check the credentials and it works for AWS S3...
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misspelled the region name:

wrong region:

```
us-east1
```

right region:

```
us-east-1
```